# Want to implement a year picker calendar in angular which has only years and the format is ''YYYY-YY" like 2023-24, 2022-23 etc

Tags: angular, angular-material, datepicker, calendar, ngx-bootstrap

Tried using ngx bootstrap and material, I am able to achieve 'YYYY' format but I want to implement YYYY-YY' where the year after hyphen is the consecutive year.

I tried using ngx bootstrap first but I was only able to achieve Yyyy format

I tried angular material and moment but still only Yyyy format. I want yyyy-yy format

Desired output is displayed in the image.